# how to restrict salesforce sending email when "Send Notification Email" is checked during case owner change

Tags: case

When a user want to change the owner of a case record manually, a salesforce standard screen pops up which has option "Send Notification Email". If user selects this checkbox, user or queue members will get a salesforce standard email saying "case so on so has been assigned to you".

My objective is to restrict salesforce from sending this email to user or queue members if someone selects the checkbox "Send Notification Email".

I know the popup screen is standard page and we cannot hide or add any validation over there to not let any user select that checkbox. But just wanted to check, is there a way to capture this on trigger or anything and restrict it from sending it to any user/queue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard email cannot be captured in trigger and we cannot restrict it from getting sent to desired user.

The only alternate solution we found is as below.

Step 1) Create a formula field (Change Owner) which will have same look and feel as that of standard Change owner.

Step 2) Create a custom LWC page which will have same look and feel as compared to Standard send email Popup field. Since LWC is a custom field developer can show and hide the send email notification checkbox based on condition.